# How to pass multiple dynamic url parameters to my pagination pages when a user searches the site using PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I was wondering how can I pass multiple dynamic url parameters to my pagination pages when a user searches the site using PHP & MySQL in order to display their results?

Here is the HTML form.

```
<form action="search.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="search" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Here is my pagination link

```
echo '<a href="search.php?s=' . ($start + $display) . '&p=' . $pages . '">'. $i .'</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add those as hidden input types, or append them to the URL

```
<form action="search.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="search" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
    <input type="hidden" name="s" value="<?php echo ($start + $display); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="p" value="<?php echo $pages; ?>" />
</form>
```

However that form is currently being posted and URLs are typically accessed with GET if that is the case you can do the following:

```
<form action="search.php?s=<?php echo ($start + $display) ?>&p=<?php echo $pages; ?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="search" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Though you really should be more clear with your question.

Comment: I want to know how to pass multiple dynamic url parameters which are the search terms the user entered into the search box.

Comment: I have generally passed it thru as normal via the url i.e.
search.php?page=x&term=urlencode("my search term") or I have used mod_rewrite to make it "appear" cleaner.

Comment: @lone what do you mean by "in the search box" the actual TEXT search box or something else?